# Looping through an Excel File as long as columns are the same

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel File in wich column A:A are names, column B:B are associated months.
Likewise (A,B): Tom JAN Tom JAN Tom NOV Tom DEC Jack SEP Jack DEC Jack AUG ...

I'm now trying to loop through this. I've overcome the first obstace by looping until the (unkown) end of the column with this "script".

```
Sub DoWhile()

Dim i As Long
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection

            
c.Add Cells(1, 1), "Name"
c.Add Cells(1, 2), "Month"
c.Add Cells(1, 3), "Volume"

i = 2
With ActiveSheet
    Do While i <= .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            c.Add Cells(i, 1), "Name"
            c.Add Cells(i, 2), "Month"
            c.Add Cells(i, 3), "Volume"
            MsgBox c.Item("Name")
            MsgBox c.Item("Month")
            MsgBox c.Item("Volume")
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

**Problem**:
Run-time error '457':
This key is already associated with an element of this collection.

It seems like I'm not allowed to use multiple values per key. How can I bypass this problem?

Doing this in other languages would be quite easy. I'd create a list with the respective column values, and cycle through that list as long as list[i-1] == list[i] ...

Could someone help me out?

Again in short:

Input:

> A   B
>
> Tom   JAN
>
> Tom   MAR
>
> John NOV
>
> John NOV
>
> John DEC
>
> Marc JUN
>
> Marc JAN
>
> ...

Output should be an excel sheet with:

> A   B   C   D
>
> Tom    JAN    -   MAR
>
> John   -    -    -
>
> Marc    JAN   - - -
>
> And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more simply:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim nA(1 To 10000) As String
Dim nB(1 To 10000) As String

i = 2
e = 0
With ActiveSheet
    Do While i <= .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If Cells(i - 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
                nB(e) = nB(e) & " - " & Cells(i, 2)
            Else
                e = e + 1
                nA(e) = Cells(i, 1)
                nB(e) = Cells(i, 2)
            End If
            MsgBox nA(e) & " : " & nB(e)
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```

you cannot use the same Key in a collection...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like the below. The code will find the current region and then resize based on the rows in A1 and the first 3 columns. I then print to the MsgBox but you can paste these onto another worksheet if required.

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer

arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, 3).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)

    MsgBox arr(i, 1)
    MsgBox arr(i, 2)
    MsgBox arr(i, 3)

Next i
```